# Como faço para pular a página do excel ao meu codigo validar determinada palavra e não ler o restante da página, com pandas e python

Tags: python, microsoft-excel, pandas

O meu código lê uma planilha e passa por todas as folhas, porém eu preciso de dados até uma determinada parte no caso até a palavra visto, e ao chegar nela eu precisava que pulasse a página e não arquivasse os demais dados, meu código  seguir:

```python
import customtkinter as ctk
from tkinter import Scrollbar, Listbox, END
import pandas as pd

# Inicialização da janela CTk
janela = ctk.CTk()
janela.geometry("1024x768")

# Leitura da folha do Excel
lista_folhas = None  # Isso fará com que todas as folhas sejam lidas
books = pd.read_excel("JANEIRO.xls", sheet_name=lista_folhas)

# Cria uma lista para armazenar os resultados
resultados = []


for sheet_name, book in books.items():
    # Encontra as linhas onde 'DESPESA' está contido na coluna 1 (segunda coluna)
    visto_presente = False
    for index, row in book.iterrows():
        if 'VISTO' in str(row[1]).upper():
            print("Palavra 'VISTO' encontrada na folha {}. Pulando para próxima folha.".format(sheet_name))
            visto_presente = True
            break
            
    if visto_presente:
        continue

        
    despesa_bool = book.iloc[:, 1].str.contains('DESPESA',  case=False, na=False)    

    despesa_df = book[despesa_bool]


    
    
    # Obtém os valores em reais das colunas 3 e 5 para as linhas onde 'DESPESA' está presente
    valores_coluna3 = despesa_df.iloc[:, 3]
    valores_coluna5 = despesa_df.iloc[:, 5]

    # Obtém os nomes das despesas correspondentes
    nomes_despesas = despesa_df.iloc[:, 1]
    

    # Cria uma série de texto contendo o nome da despesa e a marcação de 'DESPESA'
    resultado_final_com_valor = nomes_despesas + " - DESPESA" + " - Valor Coluna 3: " + valores_coluna3.astype(str) + " - Valor Coluna 5: " + valores_coluna5.astype(str)


    
    # Adiciona os resultados à lista
    
    resultados.extend(resultado_final_com_valor)
   

print(book)    
   

        


# Cria e posiciona a barra de rolagem
scrollbar = Scrollbar(janela)
scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")

# Cria e posiciona a lista
lista_resultados = Listbox(janela, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
for resultado in resultados:
    lista_resultados.insert(END, resultado)
lista_resultados.pack(side="top", fill="both")

# Associa a barra de rolagem à lista
scrollbar.config(command=lista_resultados.yview)

# Loop principal da GUI
janela.mainloop()
```

Quero que pule a página sem pegar os dados a baixo da validação